# Best way to creating setup of C# application

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

Hi i am recently working on a c# window form application. I have done the all stuff and noe it's time to deploy the application, But i am unable to activate the visual studio installshield feature. Can any one here able to tell me any alternet way to create me a setup file of my application. Like Innosetup compiler or other.

Comment: I believe it depends on the version of VS you are using? What version do you have?

Comment: @PeterSmith: He's tagged his post with VS2013.

Comment: You could use the click-once installer.

Comment: @PeterSmith vs 2013

Comment: Sorry, I meant edition rather than version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer to use InnoSetup, which is free for any use including commercial.

You can have a UI to make creation simple, but if you want really complex functionality you can write code to create those functions.  There is a thriving community of developers that use and contribute to the product, so finding examples is usually easy, but you do have to write your code in Delphi / Pascal.

On the other hand, all the Microsoft options are overly complicated and difficult to get working sensibly so I am pleased to avoid them. Corporate installers are good but incredibly expensive... so really there is no comparison.  Ease of use, and free - what more could you ask for?

I should point out that I have absolutely no connection with the product other than that I have used it for many years for many products and have absolutely no complaints.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio Setup Project is easy to work with and is available for both [VS2013](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9abe329c-9bba-44a1-be59-0fbf6151054d) and [VS2015](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f1cc3f3e-c300-40a7-8797-c509fb8933b9) in the form of Visual Studio Extension (separately from the default VS installer). Download figures suggest that a whole lot of people are using this extension.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on your needs.
Mostly you can just create an msi installer with an installer project type on VS.

The problem is that a lot of software distributors require an exe file type. For that you can use the free (limited ) edition of install shield : http://learn.flexerasoftware.com/content/IS-EVAL-InstallShield-Limited-Edition-Visual-Studio

It has everything that a standard installer needs and I use it to distribute my software.

I tried other free msi to exe programs but none of them worked well (this was a while a go and maybe things changed since then)

Comment: I have earlier tried offline activation of InstallShield but how to switch online activation